# How to import tailwindcss/colors?

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I am trying to make the extended pallet work as outline in here
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#color-palette-reference

I have installed tailwind, but only have the default colors.

[image]

When I try and add the code with the `;` or without it doesn't work.

[image]

I than realized the file is missing.

[image]

How do you get this file? I know I have tailwind working because the regular color scheme works and all the other functionalities. I just can't seem to get the custom colors to work ,and I really don't want to manually add all of them if I can prevent it lol

I am referring to these extended ones

[image]

Any help much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Inside your `node_modules` folder there are two Tailwindcss folders

- `@tailwindcss`
- `tailwindcss`

These two folders refer to the packages inside your `package.json`

```
{
  // .. other stuff

  "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.3.0",
        // ... other packages
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.1"
    }
}
```

Inside the `tailwindcss` folder you can spot a `colors.js` file which is the one imported in your `tailwind.config.js`

```js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        // Colors you want to add go here
        rose: colors.rose,
        cyan: colors.cyan
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here I extend the colors already included by using the `extend` node within `theme`.

Finally, run `npm run dev` and reload or delete your web browser's cookies to see the changes.